# Trying to delete ID matched file in directory with PHP and XPath

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath, domdocument

I am using the `unlink()` method to the delete the file, but I think my syntax to get the string from my XML file is applying the wrong value. The file still remains undeleted but the good news is the script returns **true** and still removes the post from the **XML**.

My **HTML** form `blog.php` sends the `$_POST["CHECK"]` value:

```
<html>
<body>

<form method="post" action="remove_post.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="CHECK" value="pst_02-02-2014_02:00:00pm"  />
   <input type="submit" name="CLOSE" value="Delete Post"  />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

My **XML** file: `data.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blog>
    <posting id="pst_01-01-2014_01:00:00pm">
        <date>01-01-2014</date>
        <time>01:00:00pm</time>
        <title>Coming!</title>
        <content>Blog Posts soon!</content>
    </posting>
    <posting id="pst_02-02-2014_02:00:00pm">
        <date>02-02-2014</date>
        <time>02:00:00pm</time>
        <title>A Blog!</title>
        <content>Blog Posts coming soon!</content>
        <image>thumb.jpg</image>
    </posting>
</blog>
```

My **PHP** file: `remove_post.php`

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST["CLOSE"] ) )
   {
   $check = $_POST["CHECK"] ;

   $doc = new DOMDocument() ;
   $doc -> load( "data.xml" ) ;
   $xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc ) ;
   $post_element = $xpath -> query( "/blog/posting[@id='$check']" ) ;

   $image_element = $xpath -> query( "/blog/posting[@id='$check']/image" ) ; // Suspected problem
   $image = "blog_images/" . $image_element -> firstChild ; // Suspected problem

   foreach ( $post_element as $post )
      {
      unlink( $image ) ;
      $post -> parentNode -> removeChild( $post ) ;
      }

   $doc -> save( "data.xml" ) ;
   header( "Location: blog.php" ) ;
   }
?>
```

...and **yes** I have checked my file permissions:

**Folder (owner) permissions:** `/blog_images/`

- read
- write
- execute

**Folder (public) permissions:**

- read
- execute

**File (owner) permissions:** `thumb.jpg`

- read
- write

**File (public) Permissions:**

- read

Comment: Try using the full absolute path `<full/path/to>/blog_images/` or perhaps `./blog_images/`

Comment: @l'L'l Tried both and no go. To be noted that my php form is under XHTML DOCtype.

Comment: @l'L'l Also I get `return false` when I use full paths `http://example.com/goes.php` in my PHP.

Comment: By full path I mean something such as `/var/www/website/public/blog_images/`

Comment: @l'L'l So like this? 
`$image = "website.com/blog_images/" . $image_element -> firstChild ;`

Comment: are getting the proper node? `$image_element` does this contain the value?

Comment: @l'L'l Via XPath - `$image_element = $xpath -> query( "/blog/posting[@id='$check']/image" ) ;`

Comment: @Xavier, No, the absolute path would be the one reflected when viewing it on your webserver. So for example, if logged in through ssh and you're in the directory `/blog_images/` you could get the absolute path by using `pwd`. You can also get the path through php (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10417279/499581)

Comment: @l'L'l I used this code to make the file so should it not be the same path to remove? `move_uploaded_file( "$temp_file , /blog_images/thumb.jpg" ) `

Comment: I couldn't tell you without seeing the function `move_uploaded_file`. Try using php example I linked by saving it (temporarily) as `cwd.php` in `/blog_images/` then view it. You'll see the absolute path.

Comment: @l'L'l Thanks for your help. The answer below was my problem. Using the `item()` method was the solution.

Comment: @Xavier, Sure thing — glad you found the issue. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the element exists, after getting the xpath value, it returns a `DOMNodeList`, so that means you have to access it first:

```
if($image_element->length > 0) { // if it exists
    $image_name = $image_element->item(0)->nodeValue;
                                  // ^ directly access it if you're expecting one value
    // thumbs.jpg
}
```

Or also you can loop it:

```
foreach($image_element as $e) {
    echo $e->nodeValue . '<br/>';
}
```

Now for unlinking:

```
unlink('blog_images/' . $image_name); // or you can add a file_exists() there just to be sure
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks very much. That is the correct way to target an element in XML using PHP.

Comment: Adding this code and removing this code `$image_element = $xpath -> query( "/blog/posting[@id='$check']/image" ) ; $image = "blog_images/" . $image_element -> firstChild ;` was the solution.