# Path to Files on server

Tags: linux, git, server, filepath

I want to use git for my sites. So I understand that I have to use SSH and initialize git in the folder. But I can't find those files and want to know what is the path for those files?

Comment: Care to give an example of one of "those files"?

Comment: Like for example its your index.php file of site example.com. In file manager On Cpanel, public_html contains all folders for different sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something I found, If you have PHP then you can use this to get absolute path

```
<?php
$path = getcwd();
echo "This Is Your Absolute Path: ";
echo $path;
?>
```

example :- `/home/user/public_html/test/test.php.`

refrence :- [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079479/how-to-get-the-absolute-path-to-the-public-html-folder)